# PHP PDO selecting columns with single quotes in their name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

In phpmyadmin, I can run this through SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `Bob's Stuff` > 1
```

But, when I run the exact same query a php script:

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `Bob's Stuff` > :int");
$stmt->bindValue(':int', $int);
$stmt->execute();
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':int AND `Bob's
>   Stuff` >= '1')' at line 10' in
>   script.php:208 Stack trace: #0
>   script.php(208): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   script.php on line 208

If I change the query column to any other column name, the query works fine.

Is it possible to have column names with apostrophes?

Comment: IMHO, having a column or a table named with an apostrophe in it is just wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that column name also as parameter,

```
$tableName = "`Bob\'s Stuff`";
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE :tableName > :int");
$stmt->bindValue(':tableName', $tableName);
$stmt->bindValue(':int', $int);
$stmt->execute();
```

By the way, one suggestion is next time don't create columns like `Bob's Stuff`. Make it single word like this `BobStuff`.

Comment: Mysql didn't support binding identifiers such as field or table names. This is literally using the value for the comparison, making it a constant t.